# redux's connect() doesn't trigger rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm fairly new to react/redux and I've encountered a problem: my `connect()` component doesn't trigger `render()`. After some debugging I was pretty surprised to see that the root of this issue lies inside of a reducer. Apparently, after my action is dispatched, the reducer somehow gets the updated state inside of it's first argument (although it should be the old state, according to the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)), and that is why `connect()` component can't receive new props. Here is my reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/action-types';

const chart = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_CHART:
            let series = [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    visible: true,
                    title: action.series[0]
                }
            ];

            for (let i = 1; i < action.series.length; i++) {
                series.push({
                    id: i,
                    visible: false,
                    title: action.series[i]
                });
            }

            return {
                id: action.id,
                series
            }

        case types.UPDATE_CHART:
            if (state.id !== action.id) {
                return state;
            }
            let result = {
                id: action.id,
                series: action.series
            };

            return {
                id: action.id,
                series: action.series
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const charts = (state = [], action) => {
    console.log('charts reducer:');
    console.log('old state:'); // it outputs the updated state
    console.log(state);
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_CHART:
            return [
                ...state,
                chart(undefined, action)
            ];

        case types.UPDATE_CHART:
            let newState = state.map(c => chart(c, action));
            console.log('new state:');
            console.log(newState);
            return state.map(c => chart(c, action));

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default charts;
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you share your ```action``` and ```component``` code from where action is dispatched?

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja I figured out a problem. The reason was that inside of the given state slice there was an object in respect of which I did mutation to. I guess it's better to extract these kind of objects into separate reducers.